# Spring with quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have created quartz application using spring 3.1.
I have created one xml file Spring-Quartz.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="runMeTask" class="com.grit.quartz.RunMeTask" />

<!-- Spring Quartz -->
<bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.grit.quartz.RunMeJob" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- <bean id="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="targetObject" ref="runMeTask" /> <property name="targetMethod" 
    value="printMe" /> </bean> -->

<!-- Simple Trigger, run every 5 seconds -->
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

</bean>

<!-- Cron Trigger, run every 5 seconds -->
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/1 * * * * ?" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="quartzProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">15</prop>
    </props>
</property>   

</bean>
```

When i am executing this file as standalone application using

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");
```

its working fine.

But i need to start this application when i am going to deploy this application in tomcat.

For this i created ServletContextListener and in context initalized i Call 
`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");`

Its working fine but after i shutdown my tomcat, Schedular still working.So how can i shutdown the schedular or is there any other way to intialize a schedular ??

Answer (score 0):

In the [Destroy method](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/) , call the [scheduler.shutdown()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ShutdownScheduler) method.

Comment: This is automatically invoked by the Spring container when the application is shutdown in an orderly fashion (actually `SchedulerFactoryBean.destroy` is called which calls `scheduler.shutdown`; I guess OP is shutting down Tomcat abruptly i.e. using `kill -9`).

Comment: it might be the case that when shutdowns is invoked , there are certain jobs which are started 
but yet to be finished. And because of this, scheduler thread is waiting for them to 
complete.

Passing the argument "false" to scheduler.shutdown can overcome such problem ,if any here.

Comment: then still OP shouldn't explicitly invoke `scheduler.shutdown(true)`. Rather use the property `<property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>` in the bean configuration. Also, I'd expect OP will say that application didn't shutdown at all...

Answer (score 0):

Add to `<props>` the following:

```
<prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons">true</prop>
```

This should make quartz's threads to terminate upon application shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

[**`Quartz`**](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) [**`Job Scheduler`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499047/5081877) is Open Source for Job Automation by scheduling Time Interval. So that the job can be executed when ever the Trigger is fired. Trigger Listeners fires at a specifid fire time.

**QuartzInitializerListener with Spring**
*When ever records get changed in DBS trigger to find and send sms*
*Dto class Which Holds DB data*

```
public class EmpDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer salary;
    private String address;

    private  List<EmpDto> empList;.....
```

*To Scedule a job/task to run at specific date & time. 
 component/class has to implement **JOB** interface and @override execute(). so that the ececute() 
   method code will be executed by scheduler when trigger is raised.*

```
public class Quartz_JOB implements Job{

    private EmpDao edao; // configure in applicationContex.xml

    public EmpDao getEdao() {   return edao;    }
    public void setEdao(EmpDao edao) {  this.edao = edao;   }
    public static Integer size;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        Date time = context.getFireTime();
        Date next_trigger_time =context.getNextFireTime();
        System.out.println("### Current Trigget Time : "+time+"### Next Trigger Time : "+next_trigger_time);

        JobKey job_key = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap(); // Get all the keys from Listener.
        System.out.println("Instance " + job_key + " of DumbJob says: " + jobSays + ", and val is: " + record_Size);
        System.out.println("Trigger Data : "+curr_Record_Size);

        System.out.println("#######Empdao : "+edao);

    }
    String jobSays;
    int record_Size;
    int curr_Record_Size;

    public int getCurr_Record_Size() {  return curr_Record_Size;    }
    public void setCurr_Record_Size(int curr_Record_Size) {
        this.curr_Record_Size = curr_Record_Size;
    }   
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**WebListener**

```
@WebListener
public class QuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {
     Scheduler scheduler = null;
     Integer size = null;

     @Override
     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContext) {
          System.out.println("Context Initialized");

          try {
      // JobDetails used to create instances of a class which Implement <<job>>
      // <<JobBuilder>> used to define/build instances of <<JobDetails>>. Which define istances of job.
             JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder
                                .newJob(Quartz_JOB.class)
                                .withIdentity("Job_ID", "Group1")
                                .usingJobData("jobSays", "Hello World!")
                                .usingJobData("recird_Size", 3)
                                .build();

      // <<Trigger>> a component that defines the scheduled 'Time Interval'. So that the given job to execute.
      // << TriggerBuilder>> used to create Trigger Instance.
             Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                                .newTrigger()
                                .withIdentity("Trigger_ID", "Group1")
                                .forJob("Job_ID", "Group1")
                                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                                .usingJobData("curr_Record_Size", edto.getEmpList().size())
                                .build();



            // Setup the Job and Trigger with Scheduler & schedule jobs
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger);                   
         }catch (SchedulerException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
      @Override
      public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContext) {
          System.out.println("Context Destroyed");
           try {
              scheduler.shutdown();
              System.out.println("Quartz stoped");
           }catch (SchedulerException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
}
```

*When ever trigger is raised, execute() method will invoke in that static variable hold record size. get current size if it differs then send an email (Write email logic in another class & call that method from execute() by passing size).*

*To [Generate](http://www.cronmaker.com/) Corn Expression*